# How do I make these Gama Sonic lanterns theft-proof?

Tags: lighting, mounting, security, solar

Does anybody have a good idea on how to secure [these solar lights](https://gamasonic.com/product/pagoda-solar-lamp-series-flat-mount-gs-104p/)?  I've mounted these to some brick posts in front of my house and a few have been stolen.

The first time the thieves were able to unscrew the lantern from the base that are secured with a threaded rod.  I used a longer threaded rod when I replaced the stolen ones, using Loctite and a double nut for even greater security.  The second time, they rocked the lantern from the base, breaking the lantern off the base.

The thieves haven't bothered with the bases; those are perfectly secure to the brick and each time they've stolen the lanterns, the bases have remained with the threaded rod exposed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. they essentially look like this installed, though these are a different model with a stouter base:

[image]

Comment: Video cameras and law enforcement (I'd be tempted to play with an electric fence charger as well, but that might be excessively hostile.) Other than that, you'd have to change to an inherently more theft-resistant design - or cage them. Be sure to mark the ones you have so they can be identified when you find the house that's sprouting them.

Comment: Large doberman would work. A big “Woof” in the face can be a brown trouser moment...

Comment: Can you mount them higher? Install a 2"pipe into the post and put the light on top of the pipe??

Comment: Thank you everyone for the comments! I was afraid there wouldn't be an easy solution aside from switching to a better design.  I'll likely try some video cameras next.